# Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in PHP

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to access my gmail account through my localhost. However, I am getting the response:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

This is my code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'myid@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .imap_last_error());
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Simple enough, the IMAP extension is not activated in your PHP installation. It is not [enabled by default](http://php.net/imap.installation). If your local installation is running XAMPP on Windows, you have to enable it as described in the [XAMPP FAQ](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-windows.html#imapphp):

> Where is the IMAP support for PHP?
>
> As default, the IMAP support for PHP is deactivated in XAMPP, because
>   there were some mysterious initialization errors with some home
>   versions like Windows 98. Who works with NT systems, can open the file
>   `"\xampp\php\php.ini"` to active the php exstension by removing the
>   beginning semicolon at the line `";extension=php_imap.dll"`. Should be:
>   `extension=php_imap.dll`
>
> Now restart Apache and IMAP should work. You can use the same steps
>   for every extension, which is not enabled in the default
>   configuration.

Comment: followed your instructions but still getting error  Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in

Comment: @SunilBhawsar Ensure that PHP is compiled with IMAP support and that either it is a built-in or that the extension file is available in the extension directory. Be sure to check the error logs as well.

Comment: Warning: imap_header(): Bad message number in.. 
Failed to retrieve headers.......  after that can you please help me short it out

Comment: Can you please check [this] Need help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745784/how-to-fetch-to-and-cc-email-using-imap-php)

Answer (score 65):

The **Installation Procedure** is always the same, but the package-manager and package-name varies, depending which distribution, version and/or repository one uses. In general, the steps are:

> **a**) at first, user privilege escalation is required, either obtained with the commands `su` or `sudo`.
>
> **b**) then one can install the absent PHP module with a package manager.
>
> **c**) after that, restarting the `apache2` HTTP daemon is required to load the module.
>
> **d**) at last, one can run `php -m | grep imap` to see if the PHP module is now available.

On **Ubuntu** the `APT` package `php5-imap` (or `php-imap`) can bei installed with `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install php5-imap
service apache2 restart
```

On **Debian**, the `APT` package `php5-imap` can be installed `aptitude` (or `apt-get`):

```
aptitude install php5-imap
apache2ctl graceful
```

On **CentOS** and **Fedora** the `RPM` package `php-imap` can be installed with `yum` (hint: the name of the package might be something alike `php56w-imap` or `php71w-imap`, when using [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) repo):

```
yum install php-imap
service httpd restart
```

On `systemd` systems, while using [systemd units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), the command to restart unit `httpd.service` is:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

The solution stated above has the problem, that when the module was already referenced in:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

It might throw a:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'imap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

That happens, because it is referenced in the default `php.ini` file (at least on Ubuntu 12.04) and a PHP module *must at most be referenced once*. Using `INI` snippets to load modules is suggested, while the the directory `/etc/php5/conf.d/` (that path may also vary) is being scanned for `INI` files:

```
/etc/php5/conf.d/imap.ini
```

Ubuntu also features proprietary commands to manage PHP modules, to be executed before restarting the web-server:

```
php5enmod imap
php5dismod imap
```

Once the `IMAP` module is loaded into the server, the [PHP IMAP Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) should then become available; best practice may be, to check if a module *is even loaded*, before attempting to utilize it.

Comment: On Ubuntu I had to execute "php5enmod imap" in addition to installing the package! - see anser of @pramod kadam below

Comment: @mattanja it depends if `conf.d/imap.ini` is being present and parsed, whether or not, while `php5enmod` is a Ubuntu specific command, which basically does nothing else than to create that file - while `php5dismod` deletes it. updated the answer, according to your suggestion.

Comment: understood. Just sayin, the answer is more complete now, thank you! (Providing the info right in the description for Ubuntu might save another few seconds for someone ;)

Comment: For PHP7 it's _apt-get install php-imap_ (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 39):

**In Ubuntu for install imap use**

```
sudo apt-get install php-imap
```

**Ubuntu 14.04 and above use**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
```

**And imap by default not enabled by PHP so use this command to enable imap extension**

```
sudo php5enmod imap
```

**Then restart your Apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: +1 it was my case :or you can go to /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and do a ln -s ../../mods-available/imap.ini ./20-imap.ini

Comment: Good call on the `php5enmod` line, wasn't in the other answers but it didn't work for me until I'd done that.

Comment: regarding http://www.php.net/manual/en/imap.setup.php on Ubuntu 14.04+ it should be
sudo apt-get install php5-imap (not php-imap)
sudo php5enmod imap

Comment: To enable imap for php7 you can run simply "sudo phpenmod imap"

Answer (score 7):

if you are on linux, edit the `/etc/php/php.ini` (or you will have to create a new extension import file at /etc/php5/cli/conf.d) file so that you add the imap shared object file and then, restart the apache server. Uncomment

```
;extension=imap.so
```

so that it becomes like this:

```
extension=imap.so
```

Then, restart the apache by

```
# /etc/rc.d/httpd restart
```

Answer (score 4):

With

```
echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

you can find out which php.ini has been used by this instance of php.

Answer (score 4):

During migration from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 I stumbled over this as well and wanted to share that as of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the IMAP extension seems no longer to be loaded per default.

Check to verify if the extension is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep php5-imap
```

should give a response like this:

```
ii  php5-imap       5.4.6-0ubuntu5   amd64        IMAP module for php5
```

if not, install it.

To actually enable the extension

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/imap.ini 20-imap.ini
service apache2 restart
```

should fix it for apache. For CLI do the same in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X with Homebrew, as obviously, PHP is already installed due to provided error we cannot run:

> **Update: Tha latest version `brew instal php --with-imap` will not work any more!!!**

```
$ brew install php72 --with-imap
Warning: homebrew/php/php72 7.2.xxx is already installed
```

Also, installing module only, here will not work:

```
$ brew install php72-imap
Error: No available formula with the name "php72-imap"
```

So, we must **reinstall** it:

```
$ brew reinstall php72 --with-imap
```

> It will take a while :-) (built in 8 minutes 17 seconds)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After changing a semicolon in the php.ini file I solved my problem. Let's see how can you solve it?

First, open **php.ini** file. **xampp/php/php.ini**

Search **extension=imap**

remove semicolon before extension and save this file.

Code before remove semicolon `;extension=imap`

Code after remove semicolon `extension=imap`

Finally, open the XAMPP Control panel and restart Apache.

Comment: this use for windows 10

Answer (score 2):

if it is centos with php 5.3 installed.

```
sudo yum install php53-imap
```

and restart apache

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: one can omit typing the /sbin - because that path is commonly contained within root's $PATH environment. Just check /root/.bashrc once - and you'll see what is given.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu with Nginx and PHP-FPM 7 use this:

sudo apt-get install php-imap

service php7.0-fpm restart
service ngnix restart

check the module have been installed
php -m | grep imap

Configuration for module imap will be enabled automatically, both at cli php.ini and at fpm php.ini

nano /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-imap.ini

Answer (score 1):

For Xampp 7.3.9

`PHP.ini`  line 913:

```
;extension=imap
```

You should remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

If your local installation is running XAMPP on Windows , That's enough :
 you can open the file "\xampp\php\php.ini" to activate the php exstension by removing the beginning semicolon at the line ";extension=php_imap.dll". It should be:

```
;extension=php_imap.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_imap.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

To install IMAP on PHP 7.0.32 on Ubuntu 16.04. Go to the given link and based on your area select link. In my case, I select a link from the Asia section. Then a file will be downloaded. just click on the file to install IMAP .Then restart apache

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/php-imap/download.

to check if IMAP is installed check phpinfo file.incase of successful installation 
IMAP c-Client Version    2007f will be shown.