# why is imap not working in PHP?

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

I'm creating a script to connect to a mailbox using IMAP everytime I run it I get this error...

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CheckContents\index.php on line 11

does anyone know why??

Comment: This is because the IMAP extension isn't installed/enabled. Contacting your hosting provider is probably a good first step if this isn't a server you control. Also, if you'd searched for this error on StackOverflow, you'd found many, many people with the same issue and information on how to fix this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap\_open() in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654453/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imap-open-in-php)

Comment: I'm running from xampp and I have looked but none of there answers work

Answer (score 2):

Add imap extension to your php setup by adding following to your `php.ini`

```
extension=php_imap.dll
```

Comment: It is all ready there, that's what is confusing me it runs fine on linux but not windows

Comment: In Windows XAMPP environment, Just remove the ;(Semi-colon) before *extension=php_imap.dll*