# php how to enable an extension

Tags: php, macos, xampp, imap

i already have xampp installed. 
the version of xampp is:

> XAMPP 5.6.12-0

I am working on:

> OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.1

I have `php.ini` in this path:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini

inside it, there is line:

```
extension=php_imap.dll
```

However, that `IMAP` extension is not loaded, I knew that because I run this command on the terminal:

```
php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
```

and this is the result I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => sqlite3
    [7] => zlib
    [8] => bcmath
    [9] => bz2
    [10] => calendar
    [11] => ctype
    [12] => curl
    [13] => dba
    [14] => dom
    [15] => hash
    [16] => fileinfo
    [17] => filter
    [18] => ftp
    [19] => gd
    [20] => SPL
    [21] => iconv
    [22] => json
    [23] => ldap
    [24] => mbstring
    [25] => session
    [26] => standard
    [27] => mysqlnd
    [28] => mysqli
    [29] => PDO
    [30] => pdo_mysql
    [31] => pdo_sqlite
    [32] => Phar
    [33] => posix
    [34] => readline
    [35] => Reflection
    [36] => mysql
    [37] => shmop
    [38] => SimpleXML
    [39] => snmp
    [40] => soap
    [41] => sockets
    [42] => exif
    [43] => sysvmsg
    [44] => sysvsem
    [45] => sysvshm
    [46] => tidy
    [47] => tokenizer
    [48] => wddx
    [49] => xml
    [50] => xmlreader
    [51] => xmlrpc
    [52] => xmlwriter
    [53] => xsl
    [54] => zip
)
```

#### my question

How to install/enable the **IMAP** extension

I searched online, and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277255/why-is-imap-not-working-in-php) , they said to add the `extension=php_imap.dll` to my `php.ini`. However, it is already there.

I continue searching, and I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/173443/how-do-i-enable-the-imap-functions-in-php), they said to do `apt-get install php5-imap`. However, I got the following error on the terminal

```
apt-get: command not found
```

Do you know how can I enable/install the IMAP extension?

Thanks

Comment: I would think you have to include an *.so file instead of *.dll because .dll is for windows.

Answer (score 0):

When using OSX uncommenting a .dll extension seems rather odd. Look for this line: extension=imap.so and uncomment, if commented. 
Afterwards restart **your apache** . Then you can check by putting a test.php file with the following content to your localhost:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

If you do so and open the site, search the site for imap. It should have something like imap as a headline with
`IMAP c-Client Version 2XXX`

If you find that entry, the extension should have loaded.

Comment: i did what you said but still the same problem,

Comment: Be more precise. The problem so far is that you don't see it in the list? did you ever try to use an imap_ command in the script?