# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function imap_open PHP

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, imap

I have followed the steps below to enable IMAP and still things are not working.

```
    sudo apt-get install php5-imap
    sudo apt-get install php5-cli
    sudo php5enmod imap 
    service php5-fpm restart
    sudo service nginx restart
```

---

I can see the IMAP extension enabled under phpinfo and also can see the extension is loaded using command
`dpkg -l | grep php5-imap`

Server: Linux and using nginx

Comment: What's your laravel version?

Comment: Make sure you've enabled the module for php5-fpm; just checking the output of `phpinfo()` under the cli won't tell you that it has been successfully enabled for the fpm version.

Comment: @TalhaF. Using laravel 5

Comment: @MatsLindh under/etc/php5/mods-enabled i can see the imap.ini present, can you please clarify how can we enabled the module for php5-fpm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654453/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imap-open-in-php

Comment: @KaushikThakkar already tried the things mentioned in shared link but unable to succeed

Comment: try this https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1376 or http://www.syntaxbook.com/post/37094-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imapopen-in-php

Comment: restart fpm and try

Comment: `enabled under phpinfo` - how/where? From CLI, or nginx, or both? There are not the same, maybe you have enabled it in one, but not the other? `Fatal Error: Call to undefined ...` - how/where do you see this error, CLI, or nginx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I haven't got the reps for comment, so...

1. Try to check your extension file, i.e. make sure that in `/etc/php5/mods-enabled/imap.ini`, the keyword `extension=/path/to/imap.so` is not commented (having `;` or `#` as its beginning of line) and your `/path/to/imap.so` file exists.
2. Try to check if you had multiple `php-fpm` services running. Use `systemctl list-unit-files | grep php` to check. If you had multiple `php-fpm` services, make sure you had installed `imap` extension to the correct `php-fpm` instance.